# Cant focus WxWidgets frame in Mac OSX compiled with SCons

Tags: c++, eclipse, macos, wxwidgets, scons

I have this WxWidgets test source code that compiles, and when run, it shows a simple frame:

```
/*
 * hworld.cpp
 * Hello world sample by Robert Roebling
 */

#include "wx-2.8/wx/wx.h"

class MyApp: public wxApp
{
    virtual bool OnInit();
};

class MyFrame: public wxFrame
{
public:

     MyFrame(const wxString& title, const wxPoint& pos, const wxSize& size);

    void OnQuit(wxCommandEvent& event);
    void OnAbout(wxCommandEvent& event);

    DECLARE_EVENT_TABLE()
};

enum
{
    ID_Quit = 1,
    ID_About,
};

BEGIN_EVENT_TABLE(MyFrame, wxFrame)
    EVT_MENU(ID_Quit, MyFrame::OnQuit)
    EVT_MENU(ID_About, MyFrame::OnAbout)
END_EVENT_TABLE()

IMPLEMENT_APP(MyApp)

bool MyApp::OnInit()
{
    MyFrame *frame = new MyFrame( _T("Hello World"), wxPoint(50,50), wxSize(450,340) );
    frame->Show(TRUE);
    SetTopWindow(frame);
    return TRUE;
}

MyFrame::MyFrame(const wxString& title, const wxPoint& pos, const wxSize& size)
: wxFrame((wxFrame *)NULL, -1, title, pos, size)
{
    wxMenu *menuFile = new wxMenu;

    menuFile->Append( ID_About, _T("&About...") );
    menuFile->AppendSeparator();
    menuFile->Append( ID_Quit, _T("E&xit") );

    wxMenuBar *menuBar = new wxMenuBar;
    menuBar->Append( menuFile, _T("&File") );

    SetMenuBar( menuBar );

    CreateStatusBar();
    SetStatusText( _T("Welcome to wxWindows!") );
}

void MyFrame::OnQuit(wxCommandEvent& WXUNUSED(event))
{
    Close(TRUE);
}

void MyFrame::OnAbout(wxCommandEvent& WXUNUSED(event))
{
    wxMessageBox(_T("This is a wxWindows Hello world sample"),
        _T("About Hello World"), wxOK | wxICON_INFORMATION, this);
}
```

Created with this simple SCons script:

```
env = Environment()
env.ParseConfig('wx-config --cxxflags --libs')

env.Program(target='wxTest/wxTest.exe',source=['src/Wxwidgets.cpp'])
```

The problem: it wont focus when I run it. The only thing I can focus is the red, yellow and green buttons in the upper left corner.
I use Eclipse as my IDE and run scons as an external tool when I build it.

Is there someone out there that know what Im doing wrong? How can I get the frame to focus?

Hope there is someone out the who can help me.

Comment: Note that you should also remove the id enum, and use the predefined wxID_EXIT and wxID_ABOUT ids which are specially handled in wxMac, in that the menu items for those commands will be moved to the proper platform-native location in the application menu. See http://wiki.wxwidgets.org/WxMac_Issues for more information.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assume you start the raw executable that is created? This does not work on Mac OS X, see [My app can't be brought to the front!](http://wiki.wxwidgets.org/WxMac_Issues)

You will have to create an application bundle for your app to work properly on Mac OS X. I don't know anything about SCons, but maybe the [wiki](http://www.scons.org/wiki/MacOSX) does help?

Comment: Aaah I didnt know that I needed a bundle. Maybe I just have to dive into how making that for my program :) thanks for the link!!